# .Net Core Get Response After Insert BsonDocument in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want get Response or ObjcetID after inserting data in moongodb. Based on the response i want send the response. The below code i am using for insert.

```
try
  {
     BsonDocument Document = BsonDocument.Parse(value.ToString());
     _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("test").InsertOne(Document);
  }
  catch(Exception Ex)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(Ex.StackTrace);
  }
```

Any one please try to help me.
Thank you...

Comment: `Document["_id"].AsObjectId` ?

Comment: how to get response after update and delete

Comment: I suggest looking at the return types of the methods you're using.